# Is there anyway to keep session even after browser close?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Since Saving cookie is not safe.
Is there anyway to keep session or set session expiration so even I close the browser and open it again. It will not redirect me again or ask me again to put my username or password.

```
public function __construct(){
session_start();
$this->check_login();
}
public function check_login(){
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
$this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$this->logged_in = true;
} else {
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
$this->logged_in = false;
}
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $database->escape_value($_POST['username']);
$password = $database->escape_value($_POST['password']);
$found_user = $user->authenticate($username,$password);
if ($found_user){
$session->login();
redirect_to('index.php');
} else {
$message = output_message("Invalid Username or Password <br />");
}
}else{
$username = "";
$password = "";
}
```

Comment: Saving a cookie with a session ID that doesn't expire is the way to go here. There is no more secure way to do what you want.

Comment: Im my current code. Everytime I close the browser and open in again it will ask again for login. Is there anyway to keep me login on the site even my browser closes?

Comment: You can set an expiration date for your cookie. That way, it will stay on even if you close and reopen the browser.

Comment: That's what I don't know how to do.
Can you show me how to do that with the above codes?
Thanks.

Comment: @Ali posted some links that should help.

Comment: where do you store your user_id in the session ($_SESSION["user_id"] = ... ) ?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

the better way to make this thing is to use cookies only because setcookie contain a timeout

Answer (score 0):

Session is only saved in the session cookie, so if the user clears the cookies the session will be removed. Cookies are not cleared when the user closes the browser. As per Ali's answer, check the lifetime of the session cookie.

If you are really interested in identifying a returning user without the use of cookies, google for "identifying user without using cookies". You will find interesting things to do, but nothing as reliable as cookie usage.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save `user_id` in the session when the user has logged in successfully.

```
if ($found_user){
    $session->login();
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $username;
    redirect_to('index.php');
}
```

And be sure `$username` is unique.